# New Linux programmer -- Trying to develop libraries

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm a new Linux programmer trying to develop shared libraries and have been able to successfully compile one in Eclipse using the Eclipse project settings; only to find that to create a Debian package I need a ./configure script! So I set up Autotools on my system, and tried to create an  Autotools project in Eclipse. I created it with the default library settings, and then renamed the .C file to a .CPP file, and changed the entry in the Makefile.am as per the documentation. I cleaned the project, rebuilt the Makefile, but for some reason it's still looking for the old .C file!!!! (No rule to make target libTest.c needed by libTest_la-libTest.lo'!
I've spend hours trying to figure this one out to no avail. Could someone please help!

Comment: `cd projectdir;`
`grep -rn "libTest.c" *`

Comment: You don't need a configure script to make a Debian package. Who told you so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .deps folder stands for dependencies.  These are generated when ./configure is run.  Doing a make distclean (if one exists) or equivalent will remove this .deps directory along with any other generated files.  The make clean only removes generated object files. 
Re-running configure *should* generate a list of source file dependencies. Invoking make itself does not re-generate the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Found out the answer was hidden in a .deps folder. Deleting the .deps folder fixed the issue. I will award the answer to whoever can explain why deleting the folder worked though, because I'm really confused on this one.

Comment: I don't think the build environment is sane. It's CRAZY!